# C++ Long Double or equivalent on ARM64

Tags: c++, software-compilation, shared-libraries

I'm having a hard time getting a straight answer about long double precision on ARM64 architecture. I'm engineering a scientific machine requiring extreme precision, and the driver, which I will write in c++, must keep rounding errors to a minumum. I'll probably use a pi 3B+ for the prototype and some sort of ARM64 architecture for the finished product, but I'm concerned about rounding errors.

I have two questions. First, is the long double supported natively in g++ on the pi with the same precision of x86_64 machines? Second, if it is not, how can I use more digits in my calculations on ARM64 architecture? I'm not averse to linking libraries.

Comment: This isn't a Pi specific question.  If I wanted an answer I would probably ask on https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/ simply because I know some who are very knowledgeable about gcc answer questions on there.

Comment: Have you tried to create a sample program that works OK on X86_64 (so you know the expected answer). Then compile on a Raspberry and compare the results. gcc on both systems should produced code that gets identical results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The libraries libboost and libboost-math install on the pi with a simple apt-get install on Ubuntu 18.04 (ARM64 version). However, the precision which can be achieved without a license is dependent upon the GMP library, but this is also available via apt-get.

```
sudo apt-get install libboost1.65-dev
sudo apt-get install libboost-math1.65-dev
sudo apt-get install libgmp-dev
```

To compile, libgmp needs to be linked to g++ via -lgmp. The following code achieves 50 digit precision, which is good enough for me.

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/gmp.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost;
using namespace multiprecision;

int main()
{
    std::cout.precision(std::numeric_limits<mpf_float_50>::digits10);
    std::cout << mpf_float_50(acos(-1.0)) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
3.141592653589793115997963468544185161590576171875
```

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/floats/gmp_float.html